# How to create Areas Registration to route another page

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I use ASP.NET MVC 4 for my app. I use redirection to another page. But it does not work. Why?

```
return RedirectToAction("Edit", new { id = x.EmployeeID });
```

Comment: Include area in route values.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add area as well:

```
return RedirectToAction("Edit", new { id = x.EmployeeID, area = "Your_Area_Name" });
```

That should transfer you to the area, but you also need to supply the controller to `RedirectToAction`.